# Custom Trie implementation in Java

Tags: java, trie

I'm trying to create a system that stores strings and for every string entry gives me the number of strings that contain the given string as substring. 
So if I have the following string

```
I am trying to create a custom implementation of a trie.
```

Now if I pass a query `tr,` it should return `trying` and `trie`.

I understand that this would need a Trie and here's what I've managed to code till now.

```
public class Trie {


    private Node root;
    private int size;

    private class Node{

        Node[] next;

        Node(){

            next = new Node[26];
        }

    }

    public Trie() {
        root = new Node();
        size = 0;
    }
    public void put(String item){
        int len = item.length();
        Node curr = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
           char c = item.charAt(i);
            curr.next[c -'a'] = new Node();
            curr = curr.next[c - 'a'];
        }
        size++;

    }
    //returns the number of strings that contain the given substring
    public int get(String str){
        int len = str.length();
        Node curr = root;
        for (int i = 0; i <len ; i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            curr = curr.next[c -'a'];
        }
    }
//this method should return the list of strings with the given substring
    public ArrayList<String> get(String str){

    }


}
```

I'm a little lost as to how can I implement the two get methods, one that returns the number of strings and another that returns the strings themselves. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that you have to precompute and store all substrings? Or is this some homework assignment?

Comment: So are you suggesting that a Trie is not the right data structure for this purpose.

Comment: No. I am merely asking why you think you have to pre-compute all possible substrings (and there will be **plenty**). I would like to understand your requirements. You see, you can easily retrieve that number each time you are asking "give me the number" of substrings. Or am I misreading the question (I simply think: you dont need a Trie for that; just do some substring calls; and then count from there).